# Alterar capa do Facebook periodicamente

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

Preciso criar um aplicativo "Campanhas de Saúde" para o Facebook.
Esse aplicativo teria que alterar a capa de todos os usuários que adicionaram esse aplicativo, todo mês, ou seja, terá uma campanha por mês.

Pensei em fazer assim: Pegar o ID do usuário do Facebook ao adicionarem o aplicativo e gravar em um BD, e ao criar uma nova camapanha, fazer um script que percorra todos os IDs, alterando a capa de cada um.

Não conheço muito o FACEBOOK SDK (PHP) do Facebook.

Seria possível fazer isso?
Caso não, alguém teria alguma ideia melhor ou mais próxima disso possível? Gostaria de fazer algo automático, para que o usuário não precise ficar trocando a capa manualmente a cada nova campanha.

Qualquer sugestão é bem vinda!

Obrigado e Feliz 2016 a todos!

Comment: Infelizmente o facebook não disponibiliza essa opção de troca da `cover` (que eu saiba) e mesmo que ele disponibilizasse não poderia alterar periodicamente sem que o usuário retornasse ao seu site, se não me engano eles não fazem isso para evitar spam.

Comment: Trocar a cover até é possível, mas não periodicamente como eu quero. Então vou ter que arrumar algum jeito de facilitar a vida do usuário, mandando um e-mail e até uma mensagem no chat dele, informando a nova campanha juntamente com o link para trocar a cover... sei lá, é uma ideia inicial.

Comment: Bom, não sabia que já era possível, pensei que só para páginas. Mas enfim, pense bem como irá fazer isso, spam irrita, e quando irrita demais o usuário deixará de seguir/acompanhar suas campanhas.